# Gltf-model export from blender. Materials are missing in a-frame

Tags: materials, three.js, gltf

I'm trying to export to gltf correct. This model is using in a-frame.
The problem is that **materials are missing** after export.
In a-frame model is represented only in black color. Settings attached.

If somebody know how to solve this, please let me know. Thanks

[Blender model]
[image: This is how it should look like (Blender)]

[A-frame]
[image: colors are missing (A-frame)]

[Export Settings]
[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glTF 2.0 specification only supports exporting PBR materials based on a metallic-roughness model.

Material support for Blender's glTF exporter only works for Cycles render materials at the moment.

And even then it requires a specific node setup to be used, as mentioned in the [user documentation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/blob/master/docs/user.md), through the use of a Node Group designed for this purpose. The node group is [available for download](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/tree/master/pbr_node) from the repository.

For future versions, EEVEE material node tree support is planned, using the Principled BSDF Shader, but it is unavailable at the moment.

Also see [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541)

Comment: Are you sure blender gltf work with nodes? I set up the material nodes based on doc, and textures are missing.

Comment: I based my answer in the documentation never tried it myself. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures